# Change "user" of a brew service

Tags: macos, homebrew, root

I have 2 brew services on my MacOS, which have their user level as **root**. I wish to change their user level to *individual users* and remove their root accesses. How can I do that?

I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling them but got no luck.

[brew-services-list command output(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyQxk.png)

[list of plist files(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fTHY.png)

PS: I'm relatively new here. So need your assistance in properly delivering the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to run brew services as non root user follow these steps:

- `sudo brew services stop redis`
- `brew services start redis`

Comment: this will prevent the service from starting at boot

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just needed to run (if the service was already running with root user)

```
sudo brew services stop <service-name>
```

for ex: `sudo brew services stop mysql`